# Handling an Observable<boolean> on Angular View from AuthService

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I'm building an auth service for an angular 5 app, currently my service has a method that looks like this:

```
public isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
 return this.getToken().map(t => {
    return t !== null;
  });
}
```

This methods returns an observable of type boolean, on my view I have this method:

```
public isLoggedIn() {
  return this.auth.isLoggedIn();
}
```

This method of course comes from the previous service.
I'm trying to show whether the user is logged in or not based on that function,
This would be the html part of it:

```
<button type="button" *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-danger">
Logout</button>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think you should pipe the result into `async' operator

Answer (score 1):

if your expression returns an Observable instance you can use `async` pipe to "extract" the data

in your particular case:

```html
<button type="button" *ngIf="isLoggedIn() | async" (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button>
```

read the docs for further reference: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Thank you, this only worked initially on the fist load, basically the service would get the token once and not listen to changes.

I ended up re-writing with just regular synchronous local storage and that works like a charm